# NodeJs Child_Process.exec can't find command

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu-18.04, child-process, arp

I'm using mz/child_process in npm, to get information about ARP's table, this works in macOS, so I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Virtual Machine in my MacBook so test the command.

```
var cp = require('mz/child_process')
   cp.exec('arp -a').then(function (stdout) {
   console.log(stdout)
})
```

I had to install manually arp with

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

but when I do `cp.exec('arp -a')` in Ubuntu I get:

> **Error: /bin/sh: 1: arp: not found**

The path is OK, in console I can run `arp -a` without problem and the where is `arp` is OK, so I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you specify it by absolute path?

Comment: No, actually it doesn't work with commands installed by apt-get.

Comment: What tool do you use for running Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Alex That's not what he asked. He asked if it works with absolute path which is not what you are doing. He is asking you to do `cp.exec('/usr/or/bin/or/some/other/path/to/arp -a')` and see if it works. Absolute path **MUST** start with `/`. If you don't know the path run `which arp`. On my system it is `/usr/sbin/arp` so I would do `cp.exec('/usr/sbin/arp -a')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the NAME command and getting error:

> bash: command name: command not found

This simply means that the relevant package net-tools which includes `arp` executable is not installed, thus missing. The package `net-tools` may not be installed on your system by default so you need to install it manually.

The package also includes aditional utilisties such as `arp, ifconfig, netstat, rarp, nameif and route`.

may be your shell is `/bin/sh`, but net-tools package puts its initialization in `~/.bashrc`, and expects `/bin/bash`.

You need to source the `arp` initialization scripts to run the commands from a non-interactive bash shell.

Comment: I already install net-tools, but it seems to doesn't work with commands installed by apt-get, I don't know if is a problem with dash (ubuntu bash) or with apt-get installer.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me with `mongodump` command, to solve it I just found the installation path with `where mongodump` (found in `/opt/homebrew/bin/mongodump`) and then execute the command with the full path.

This was my script:

```
const util = require("util");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const execAsync = util.promisify(exec);

const timestamp = moment().format("YYYYMMDD_HHmmss");

const backupDir = `./backup-dir/${timestamp}`;
const backupCommand = `/opt/homebrew/bin/mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://url" --out ${backupDir}`;

async function main() {
  try {
    await execAsync(backupCommand);
  } catch (error) {
    let errorMessage = `Error running mongodump: ${error}`;
    console.error(errorMessage);
  }
}

main();
```